# WKWebView not showing image properly Instagram embed

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have problem with instagram image in my WKWebView. It does not shows properly. It show only 20% of that image

[image]

```
<html><head><script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></head><body><p>Vest je potvrdio njegov sin Rik putem društvene mreže Instagram.</p>
<blockquote class="instagram-media" style="background: #FFF; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width: 658px; padding: 0; width: calc(100% - 2px);" data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bkc6yKGB3C9/" data-instgrm-version="8">
<div style="padding: 8px;">
<div style="background: #F8F8F8; line-height: 0; margin-top: 40px; padding: 50.0% 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
<p style="color: #c9c8cd; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 8px; overflow: hidden; padding: 8px 0 7px; text-align: center; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><a style="color: #c9c8cd; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 17px; text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bkc6yKGB3C9/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">A post shared by Rick Harrison (@rick_harrison)</a> on <time style="font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px;" datetime="2018-06-25T14:58:50+00:00">Jun 25, 2018 at 7:58am PDT</time></p>
</div>
</blockquote>
<p><br />"On je bio moj heroj. Kroz svoj život dotakao je duše mnogih ljudi, učio ih vrednostima života i porodice, teškog rada i humora", napisao je.</p>
<p>Ričard Harison rođen je 4. marta 1941. u Leksingtonu, Severna Karolina. U trenutku smrti imao je 77 godina.</p>
<p>"Zvezde zalagonica" je jedna od najpopularnijih emisija Histrory Channela od prvog emitovanja 2009. godine, koja gledaoce vodi kroz rad zalagaonice u Las Vegasu.</p>
<script async defer src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js">     </script>
<style>img{display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%;}</style>
<style>iframe{display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%;}</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the link ?

Comment: I get the html data from server. 

Please check below
I am not able to share file here

Comment: I have just upgraded my question, you can see the complete html code which I am getting from server

Comment: I found the solution for it. After removing iFrame tag, its working fine